# React-native click button while keyboard is presented

Tags: react-native

I have several inputs fields that are presented one after the other using flatlist and smartView that represents each input, with the structure being like this:

```js
    <View>
    <Dialog>
    <View >
    <KeyboardAvoidingView>
    <FlatList
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <SmartView //structure of view per input
 <SafeAreaView>
<View>
   <InputItem/>
 <TouchableNativeFeedback/> //button that must be clicked
</View>
 </SafeAreaView>
 />
    )}>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
    </Dialog>
    </View >
```

The class `<InputItem/>` contains the  `<TextInput>` in question and the `<TouchableNativeFeedback/>` is on the same level as the `<InputItem/>`

I just need for the button to register a click WHEN KEYBOARD is showing, as this app is running on iPad and keyboard do not come in they way of anything.
Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed issue by adding `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"always"}` to component `<Dialog>`.

Comment: Guys just add: keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"always"}
In your flatlist, virtualized list or recycler list view

Answer (score 1):

Add this prop to your `FlatList` so that touches will get detected even though the keyboard is opened: `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"` or `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"`

Comment: unfortunately, I have already tried this approach but nothing seemed to change. the keyboard is still being dismissed and button is not being clicked. 
This is why I attached the structure of the views, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Guys just add: keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"always"}
In your flatlist, virtualized list or recycler list view